# Run time estimation of mice imputation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, missing-data, imputation

I have used mice imputation to fill missing values of a machine learning dataset. The dataset is huge, 11726412 row and 30 columns. Here is the number of missing values in this data:

```
In [2]:X.isnull().sum()

Out[2]: 
time                           0
count_neshan                   0
count_scat_o             4059792
count_avl_en_o           7364664
count_avl_ex_o           7364664
count_anpr_o             9646200
karmnd_dr_mhl_shghl_o          0
veh_own_o                      0
n_bussi_unit_o                 0
park_area_o                    0
area_o                         0
office_land_use_o              0
n_office_o                     0
commercial_unit_o              0
n_commercial_o                 0
schl_o                         0
count_scat_d             4059792
count_avl_en_d           7364664
count_avl_ex_d           7364664
count_anpr_d             9646200
karmnd_dr_mhl_shghl_d          0
veh_own_d                      0
n_bussi_unit_d                 0
park_area_d                    0
area_d                         0
office_land_use_d              0
n_office_d                     0
commercial_unit_d              0
n_commercial_d                 0
schl_d                         0
dtype: int64
```

I ran this code to impute missing values in the dataset:

```
from impyute.imputation.cs import mice

imputed_train_data = mice(X.values)
```

This is the first time I am using mice and, I have no estimation of the time it will take to run. I conducted this code 8 days ago and it is still running.

I could not find anything about the run time of mice. All I know is "it's slow".
I would appreciate it if anyone experienced with the subject could estimate the time or suggest a faster alternative considering the big dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://impyute.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/cross_sectional_imputation.html#impyute.imputation.cs.mice) `mice` runs until convergence which is defined as less than 10% change between consecutive updates on **all** imputed values. This means that it is unpredictable when it will stop. My intuition would say that the probability of **none** of the imputation updates being smaller than 10% becomes very small with a large number of missing values.

Seeing that the [source code](https://impyute.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/impyute/imputation/cs/mice.html#mice) is actually rather simple, you could write your own version that limits the number of iterations. It seems that one comment in the source actually indicates that this was the case for the original implementation at some point:

> # Step 5: Repeat step 2 - 4 until convergence (the 100 is arbitrary)

You could replace the `while all(converged):` with `for _ in range(max_iterations):`.